# how to run an old .BAS file

Tags: file, launch

i have an old .BAS file that im trying to launch. I just need the program to work - i don't need to edit or do anything with the code. Does anybody know how to run it so i can see the program - its an old  solitaire game i use for an example to show how the code is written. Can i run it through visual studio 2010 - if yes how? Or with program should i use to launch it?

```
  Public Class Form1
  SCREEN 9,0 'medium resolution'
  FORGRUND%=4
  BAGGRUND%=63
  PILE%=9
  DUG%=2
  RUNDE%=1
  ANTFLYT%=0
  ANTKONGER%=0
  KONGE13%=0
  COLOR FORGRUND%,BAGGRUND%:CLS:KEY OFF
  OPTION BASE 1 'laveste v‘rdi i tabeller s‘ttes til 1'
'*********************************************************'
' en lille startmelodi til at komme ignag med'
'*********************************************************'
'PLAY "mb o3 l8 ffffafffafdfe4.l8 eeeegeeedefed4" kattekilling
  PLAY "mb o3 t255 l8 df+ga2df+ga2df+gl4af+df+e2l8f+f+ed4.df+4aaag2f+gl4af+ded2"
'*********************************************************'
'lav en konverteringstabel'
'*********************************************************'
  GOSUB 2060
'*********************************************************'
'lav kasser s† de er flotte'
'*********************************************************'
  GOSUB 2260
'*********************************************************'
'2 tabeller: randomizer, kort'
'randomizer initieres med vilk†rlige tal'
'*********************************************************'
  GOSUB 2640
'*********************************************************'
'vi skal putte kortet p† rette plads p† bordet/sk‘rmen'
'*********************************************************'
  GOSUB 2840
'*********************************************************'
'l‘s bord og flyt til sk‘rm'
'*********************************************************'
  GOSUB 2950
'*********************************************************'
'pr›v at l‘se F fra sk‘rm'
'*********************************************************'
  X=6
  Y=3
  FRASKARMX%=0 'initier fra-koordinat til brug ved mark›rbev‘gelser'
  FRASKARMY%=0 'initier fra-koordinat til brug ved mark›rbev‘gelser'
  COLOR PILE%,BAGGRUND%
  LOCATE X,Y:PRINT CHR$(24)
  COLOR FORGRUND%,BAGGRUND%
  LOCATE 23,2:PRINT"V‘lg kort der skal flyttes ved at       
  taste                                    "
  FUNDET=1
  WHILE FUNDET 's†l‘nge F ikke er indtastet'
  FT$=INKEY$:IF FT$="" THEN LOCATE 1,72:PRINT TIME$:GOTO 510
  IF LEN(FT$)=1 GOTO 630
  IF LEN(FT$)=2 GOTO 560 'evt. mark›r bev‘gelse'
  GOTO 680 'til endwhile'
      'find mark›r-bev‘gelse'
  FT$=RIGHT$(FT$,1)
  IF ASC(FT$)=77 THEN GOSUB 1660 'pil til h›jre'
  IF ASC(FT$)=75 THEN GOSUB 1750 'pil til venstre'
  IF ASC(FT$)=72 THEN GOSUB 1850 'pil op'
  IF ASC(FT$)=80 THEN GOSUB 1940 'pil ned'
  GOTO 680
      'find bogstav'
  IF (FT$<>"f") AND (FT$<>"F") AND (FT$<>"a") AND (FT$<>"A") AND (FT$<>"N") AND       
  (FT$<>"n") AND (FT$<>"b") AND (FT$<>"B") GOTO 680
  FUNDET=0
  WEND
```

etc

Comment: Looks like VB6, which is not compatible with VB.Net (Google will happily list all the flamewars on the subject).

Comment: Actually it looks like QBASIC from MSDOS.

Answer (score 0):

VB2005 Express has an upgrade wizard. It opens automatically when you try to open a VB6 project.

Answer (score 0):

This must be VB for DOS, (versions 1.0, not sure if 2.0 was ever made), its not qb since it has forms support (QB didnt have that) and its not Windows version since it has this SCREEN and COLOR statements (for console  text resolution and colors) :

> SCREEN 9,0 '**medium resolution' switch 0=nocolor 1=color
> mode 9 with 0 no color

> SCREEN 9: 640 x 350 graphics
> 80 x 25 or 80 x 43 text format, 8 x 14 or 8 x 8 character box
> 16 colors assigned to 4 attributes (64K adapter memory), or 64 colors assigned to 16 attributes (more than 64K adapter memory)
> If 64K EGA adapter memory, 1 video memory page (0); otherwise, 2 pages (0-1)

> ```
> COLOR FORGRUND%,BAGGRUND%:CLS:KEY OFF
> ```

looking that there are GOTO and GOSUBS with line number labels and the KEY OFF command, example code was ported from GWBasic that had line numbers in it and had 25th line displaying functions keys commands (turned off by key off).